# Cant parse DataSnapshot from Firebase into java Class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im having this problem while trying to convert snapshot from firebase into the Event class. The Event object (evento var) is created but its attributes are all null.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("events")
                .orderByChild("event_name").equalTo(event_name)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        Event evento = snapshot.getValue(Event.class);
                        for (Task task:
                             evento.getTasks()) {
                            Log.d("Task name:",task.getName());
                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                    }
                });
```

This is the Event class

```
public class Event {
    private String event_name;
    private List<Task> tasks;

    public Event(String event_name, LinkedList<Task> tasks) {
        this.event_name = event_name;
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }

    public Event() {
    }

    public String getEvent_name() {
        return event_name;
    }

    public void setEvent_name(String event_name) {
        this.event_name = event_name;
    }

    public List<Task> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }

    public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }

}
```

And this is the Task class, just in case

```
public class Task {
    private String name;
    private Boolean state;
    private String description;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Boolean getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(Boolean state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Task(String name, Boolean state, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.state = state;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public Task(){

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you update the question to show the structure of the `events` node within your Firebase database?

Comment: thanks Pat too! i was about to upload the node structure when Frank answered it and it solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the JSON (as Pat asked in a comment), it is impossible to be certain. But most likely, you're converting the type in the wrong place.

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result. So your code need to loop over the result(s) to get at each matching event.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("events")
            .orderByChild("event_name").equalTo(event_name)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot eventSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Event event = eventSnapshot.getValue(Event.class);
                        Log.d(event.getEvent_name());
                        for (Task task: event.getTasks()) {
                            Log.d("Task name:",task.getName());
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                    throw error.toException(); // don't ignore errors
                }
            });
```